# Pre-installed Maven on Mac OS X gives java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, macos, maven

I tried to run pre-installed Maven with `mvn` command and get this error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/launcher/Launcher`

Running latest Mac OS X Mountain Lion and Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check which version of Maven & Java you are using.

Your use case looks similar to the following blog post found online.

http://cyntech.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/maven-2-error/

Comment: Solved the problem by deleting built-in Maven completely and moving the fresh Maven 3 install into /usr/local/maven. Thought of that solution after reading article you provided :).

Answer (score 2):

That looks very familiar.  I have seen that when M2_HOME was set to a Maven2 installation.

Do you have M2_HOME, or MAVEN_HOME set?  This could be the culprit.

There are some pretty major bugs in maven 3.0.3. There are also really nice performance gains in 3.0.4 related to the maven http wagon, including connection pooling.  If you find that your builds are running slower, do a mvn --version.  The version that ships with Lion is 3.0.3.

To fix this, do the following:

brew install maven
sudo unlink /usr/share/maven
cd /usr/share/
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4 maven

Making sure that the M2_HOME and MAVEN_HOME variables aren't set is pretty key to issues like this (for some reason Mac OS X doesn't need them and it causes issues).  That's the usual culprit.  I would encourage you to upgrade to 3.0.4 as well though for the httpclient improvements if nothing else.

Comment: Forgot to add...  check your JDK version too and make sure that the JDK you are using is compatible with the version of Maven you are invoking.  Being 3.0.3 it should be just fine with everything but jdk 1.4 and below, but I have to add this for completeness.